# Performing mathematical operations on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The column looks like

```
 Mod_month  Mod_year    Reg_Year    Reg_Month  
 10          2016       2016         10

 1           2018       2016         12

 2           2017       2017         2
```

I want to perform some mathmatical operations on coloumns of a dataframe to calculate difference between dates.

I've tried using:

```py
df['difference']=df[df['mod_month']-df['last_month']+df['mod_month']*12-df['last_year']]
```

Which returns the Error:

```py
KeyError: '[-1896 -2015 -1993 ... -1955 -1877 -1981] not in index'
```

Which I think is due to null values, I also tried using `coerce = 'True'`, which returns `invalid syntax`.

I have seen other posts, but none of them has the error that I have, therefore any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Rakesh how did you change the table to correct format, I tried doing it but the editor does not take space or tab. Thanks for the edit

Comment: use 4 spaces in front of a code line and a blank line before and after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need remove `df[]`, because it is syntax of [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or selecting by `subset` of columns:

```
df['difference'] = df['mod_month'] - df['last_month'] + df['mod_month'] * 12 - df['last_year']
```